# Create a new file exploiting a command in a WebIDE plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, command, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I am developing a SAP WebIDE plugin and I need to give the user the possibility to create a new file right clicking on a custom project and executing my plugin command. Something similar occurs when you right click on a folder and select New>SAPUI5 view: running this command creates for you a view and its controller in the project tree.
How can I archieve that? I looked at the code of the service that takes care of the documents management but the `createNew` method is not implemented, yet.
I was also considering to use the template service but I didn't find any documentation on how to call it through a command rather than through the template extension mechanism.
Any help would be very appreciated.